# How to compile a single line of C++ code in gcc or g++ using Linux terminal like python?

Tags: gcc, gnome-terminal

One can run **python** command in terminal

Example:

```
>>> 2 + 3

5

>>>
```

Can one compile a single line of code without writing it in a text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really like in Python but on Unix-like systems you can use
here-documents to type text in the terminal and pipe it to `gcc` and
run output `a.out` like that:

```
(
cat <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
puts("Hello World");

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
EOF
 ) | gcc -xc - && ./a.out
```

After typing the first two lines:

```
(
cat <<EOF
```

start typing your program source code and type

```
EOF
 ) | gcc -xc - && ./a.out
```

to compile and run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an error-free one-line compile:-

```
$ echo "int foo() { return 42; }" | gcc -xc -fsyntax-only -c -
```

And here's one with a problem:

```
$ echo "void foo() { return 42; }" | gcc -xc -fsyntax-only -c -
<stdin>: In function ‘foo’:
<stdin>:1:21: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void
<stdin>:1:6: note: declared here
```

`-fsyntax-only` directs gcc to parse your syntax only, producing no object file, which I guess is what your after.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't compile a single line of code. It interprets a single line of code and updates its own state so that the next line of code knows the result of the previous one.

```
 >>> x = 2 + 3
 >>> x + 4
 9
```

This is called [REPL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

There's nothing like that possible for C. One can concoct a tool to read and execute one-line C programs, however each line would be a complete program, totally unaware from any other line. This is not interesting in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

CERN has developed a C++ interpreter that does exactly (well, not exactly, but very close to) what the python interpreter does. You can find more information on [its website](https://root.cern.ch/cling).

It uses Clang heavily internally, so if you are building it from source you'll need LLVM/Clang available.

Comment: you don't need llvm available. root ships the llvm parts it needs https://github.com/root-project/root/tree/master/interpreter/llvm (strongly simplified explanation: it's necessary whenever cling uses llvm features that have been shipped to llvm but aren't yet released in llvm)